# Discord Modal not updating TextInput label after updating it (Python)

Tags: python, forms, discord, modal-dialog, bots

I've been learning how to write bots for past couple of days and got general idea, but for now I'm stuck with this problem:

```
class FormButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Moderator form", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def moderatorBtn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        rand = random.randint(0, len(config.moderator_questions) - 1)
        new_modal = moderation_modal()
        new_modal.question = ui.TextInput(label = config.moderator_questions[rand], style = discord.TextStyle.paragraph, placeholder = f"{rand}", required = True, max_length = 128)
        await interaction.response.send_modal(new_modal)
        await new_modal.wait()
            

class moderation_modal(ui.Modal, title = "Example modal"):
    question = ui.TextInput(label = "Hello!", style = discord.TextStyle.paragraph, placeholder = "Not sure!", required = True, max_length = 128)
    
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        channel = bot.get_channel(config.form_result_channel)
        embed = discord.Embed(title = self.title, description = f"**{self.answer.label}**\n{self.answer}", timestamp = datetime.now(), color = discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.set_author(name = interaction.user, icon_url = interaction.user.avatar)
        await channel.send(embed = embed)
        await interaction.response.send_message(content=config.response_completed_form, ephemeral=True)
```

So, I have array with strings, that represents different questions for users and want them to change in title of `new_modal.question.label`. I need to generate new question even when user re-open modal without submiting it.

I tried checking if `new_modal.title` has changed by simply typing its title in the chat and there it all works fine and title changes every time I press "Moderator form" button, but when I try to send modal, it simply stays the same as in `moderation_modal.question.title`.

Is there a function to update modal UI or any other workaround to make title change everytime user re-open a modal?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while debugging some modal values and placeholders with Discord.js. The modal on my Discord desktop app would not immediately reflect changes I made to the bot's modal code.

I was able to force modals to change by shutting my Discord desktop app down completely and restarting it.

There may be a cache to sweep, but I'm not aware of it at the moment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34923133)